# Why does FQL always request me to reduce the amount of data I ask for?

Tags: facebook-fql

No matter which query I try:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?fql=SELECT%20object_id%2C%20src_small%2C%20src_big%2C%20caption%2C%20modified%20FROM%20photo%20WHERE%20album_object_id%3D154766101216210%20AND%20modified%3E1449682235%20AND%20owner%3D154763454549808%20ORDER%20BY%20modified%20DESC

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?fql=SELECT%20object_id%20FROM%20photo%20WHERE%20album_object_id%3D154766101216210%20AND%20modified%3E1449682235%20AND%20owner%3D154763454549808%20ORDER%20BY%20modified%20DESC

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?fql=SELECT%20object_id%2C%20src_small%2C%20src_big%2C%20caption%2C%20modified%20FROM%20photo%20WHERE%20album_object_id%3D154766101216210%20AND%20modified%3E1449682235%20AND%20owner%3D154763454549808%20ORDER%20BY%20modified%20DESC%20LIMIT%201
```

It always ends up saying:

> {
>     "error": {
>       "code": 1,
>       "message": "Please reduce the amount of data you're asking for, then retry your request"
>     }
>   }

What's the idea? why does nothing works?
P.S. it works sometimes, but you can try the same query one second later, and it won't work anymore.

I would like to somehow get the first query to work.

Comment: you can try with a limit in the query, but why even use FQL? it is deprecated and does not work in newer apps anymore. even in (very old) apps, it will stop working in august 2016.

Comment: See the examples I gave, there's limit 1 and it still says this error.

Comment: About not using FQL, its not an option for me, I have asked a question how these queries can be achieved using Graph API and it seems not to be possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27519559/change-from-fql-to-graph-api

Comment: If you know how can I achieve the first query using graph API I would be glad.